# Scroll to top of Foundation accordion on click - offset calculation

Tags: asp.net, zurb-foundation, accordion

I have a Foundation accordion. When I click on one of the accordion anchors, I want it to scroll to the top of the current panel (although just to the top of the accordion control would be OK). The panels vary in size depending on the content. So the offset is I think screwed up. The first click works, because the offset calculation is correct. But on subsequent click, I think is calculating the location, then scrolling. But during the scroll, the new panel loads and the offset changes. So it scrolls somewhere to the middle of the panel. At least that's my theory. Even more confusing, its actually a tab control that falls back to an accordion for small screens.

Here is the accordion:

```
<dl class="accordion" data-accordion>
    <dd class="accordion-navigation active">
        <a class="show-for-small-only" href="#panel11">First Panel</a>
        <div class="content active" id="panel11">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="medium-12 columns">
                    <div class="panel radius">
                        <h1 class="text-center">Some Header Text</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="medium-4 columns end">
                    //Some content...             
                </div>
                <div class="medium-4 columns">
                    //Some content...          
                </div>
                <div class="medium-4 columns">
                    //Some content...        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="show-for-small-only" href="#panel21">Second Panel</a>
        <div class="content active" id="panel21">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="medium-12 columns">
                    <div class="panel radius">
                        <h1 class="text-center">Some Header Text</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="medium-4 columns end">
                    //Some content...             
                </div>
                <div class="medium-4 columns">
                    //Some content...          
                </div>
                <div class="medium-4 columns">
                    //Some content...        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

And here is the scrolling script:

```
<script>
    $(".accordion dd > a").click(function () {
        var href = $(this).attr("href")
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: ($(href).offset().top)
        }, 1000);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was the final solution that worked:

```
$(".accordion dd > a").click(function () {
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            theOffset = $(self).offset();
            $('body,html').animate({ scrollTop: theOffset.top - 100 });
        }, 310);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, in your script check the href part. Should be something like

`var elem = $(this);
$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: elem.offset().top
}, 1000);`

Comment: That just breaks the accordion (meaning clicking on accordion does nothing).

Comment: I mean just before exiting the function and after the animation

Comment: This breaks the accordion: $(".accordion dd > a").click(function () {
            var href = $(this).attr("href")
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: ($(href).offset().top)
            }, 1000);
            return false;
        });

Comment: Hold on a sec, in the code above panels have same id's. Have you checked that?

Comment: Thats a cut and paste with my code sample on SO. Fixed question